# How to select the first frame of a clip?

Tags: final-cut-pro

I want to select this frame right here, can I do it?

[image]

This happens all the time where I have two clips together and I have a transition in between them. Now I want to tighten up the transition by removing some frames from the clips on either side. Here is what I do:

1. Delete the transition.
2. Select the clip on the right (or the left).
3. Click again to get the first frame.
4. Use the <kbd>,</kbd> and <kbd>.</kbd> keys to nudge/extend that edge of that clip.
5. Reconfigure and re-add the transition.

Getting this right can require repeating this process maybe 5 or 10 times.

Answer (score 1):

Up-arrow will do the trick. Down-arrow takes you to the first frame of the next clip.

Trick: if you're looking for the *last* frame of a clip, go to the start of the next one, then use back-arrow once to move back a frame.